# Split single row across rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

Given a `Promotion` table with rows and data such as:

```
PromotionId    Codes
1              a,b
2              c
3              d,e,f
```

How could I write a query to return it like this:

```
PromotionId    Codes
1              a
1              b
2              c
3              d
3              e
3              f
```

Basically I want to string split the Code over multiple rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `Split` table-valued-function, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Then you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to join with it:

```
SELECT PromotionId, CodeList.Item AS Codes
FROM Promotion p
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Codes, ',') CodeList
```

**Edit**: Here's a fiddle with your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85f8b/1/0

Result:

```
PROMOTIONID    CODES
  1             a
  1             b
  2             c
  3             d
  3             e
  3             f
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using SQL with XML like the following:

```
declare @X xml

SET @X= (SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<s id="'+cast(PromotionId as varchar)+'">' + REPLACE(Codes,',','</s><s id="'+cast(PromotionId as varchar)+'">') + '</s>') FROM t1
FOR XML RAW)

SELECT c.value('(@id)[1]','int') as PromotionId, c.value('.','varchar(50)') as Code
FROM @X.nodes('/row/s') T(c)
```

It will be more efficient and faster

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db8a/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the most fastest way to split/contact things in T-SQL is using XML. Here is the solution I used:

```
;WITH CTE(PromotionID,Codes)
AS
(
    SELECT  PromotionID
           ,CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(Codes, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML) AS Codes
    FROM @SourceTable
)
SELECT  PromotionID
       ,Code
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)'))) AS Code FROM Codes.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)) AS List
```

I have used the Common Table Expression to cast the codes as XML. Then I am using just a common way to split the XML into individual elements. Here is the full working example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @SourceTable TABLE
(
    PromotionID INT,
    Codes NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @SourceTable (PromotionID,Codes)
VALUES   (1,'a,b')
        ,(2,'c')
        ,(3,'d,e,f')

;WITH CTE(PromotionID,Codes)
AS
(
    SELECT  PromotionID
           ,CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(Codes, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML) AS Codes
    FROM @SourceTable
)
SELECT  PromotionID
       ,Code
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)'))) AS Code FROM Codes.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)) AS List


SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: The `Split` has the advantage that you often need such a function, apart from that it depends which one is faster. This suggests that the `Split` is more efficient(at least sometimes): http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/01/05/using-xml-to-pass-lists-as-parameters-in-sql-server/ (_"Split function, scales beautifully as shown by the red line, and it is difficult to measure it, it is so quick. The XML eShred technique by contrast, using the element-based list, and this XQuery syntax, exhibits horrible scaling"_)

Comment: I have a lot of types "Split" functions using XML as well. Your split function is incredibly slow, because, first it is using LOOP and second it is using string operators (it is a well known fact how slow the strings, especially the big ones are handle by the SQL Server). So, using XML is faster, and it requires several rows of code only.

Comment: I haven't measured both approaches and i don't think that mine has more lines or is difficult to understand: `SELECT PromotionId, CodeList.Item AS Codes
FROM Promotion
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(Code, ',') CodeList`. However, normally you'd need such a function usually in situations like importing. It shoud not be normal to use a comma(or whatever) separated string as input or store it in the database when you could store it as separate record.

Comment: There is no matter if the separator is ',' or '|' or anything else - the function can easily handle this. Anyway, I am agreed with you that in the most(but not all)cases this will be used when data is imported.